# How can I set a deposit tag for XRP transactions using the Coinbase API?

Tags: coinbase-api

I am playing with the Coinbase API and am attempting to send XRP from my Coinbase wallet to another account (outside of Coinbase). The Coinbase send API (https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#send-money) allows me to set the destination address but there is no means of setting the destination tag, which is required for XRP transfers.

How can I set the destination tag?

Answer (score 0):

The Coinbase Pro API has documentation for their platform that hints at a possible solution (https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/?r=1#crypto).  Two parameters of interest are destination_tag and no_destination_tag.  So if you want to send XRP using Python, you might say the following:

```
client.send_money(account_id = <account-id>,
                  to = <destination-address>,
                  amount = <amount>,
                  currency = 'XRP',
                  destination_tag = <destination-tag>,
                  no_destination_tag = False)
```

If you don't want to use the destination tag, you can just omit the destination_tag parameter and set no_destination_tag to True.

Answer (score 0):

Extremely late to this but figured it'll be useful for someone else stumbling onto this thread.

I've just tested putting deposit_tag into the POST request to Coinbase's API (not Coinbase Pro) and it successfully puts the deposit tag through.

Coinbase also doesn't allow you to send XRP if you don't specify a deposit tag, which is handy.